# Debian. Can't umount loop device

Tags: debian, mount, virtualbox, loop-device

Debian 8.2. I want to umount the `/dev/loop5` device that I mounted, but I can't. I'm getting the message that

> /dev/loop5 is not mounted.

Could anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here, please?

```
touch file
mkdir /mnt/partition
dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=1M count=10
losetup /dev/loop5 file
mkfs.ext2 /dev/loop5
mount –t auto –o loop /dev/loop5 /mnt/partition
umount /dev/loop5
```

Comment: how about  `umount /mnt/partition`?

Comment: I forgot to mention- This works, yea. But I'm trying to get the /dev/ one, because I want to undelete files with mc which requires the /dev/partition way. I'm still learning tho, that's why I don't know much about that stuff.

Comment: https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/mount/umount.8.en.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you didn't mount `/dev/loop5`.

`mount -oloop SRC MNT` means to create a loop device for the file SRC, and then mount that loop device at MNT.  Apparently SRC is allowed to be a loop device itself if you really want :).

You could have seen this in the output of `mount` or `findmnt`; they would show that the loop device `/dev/loop5` is not mounted and a different loop device is mounted.

Answer (score 2):

`man losetup` shows:

> Detach all associated loop devices:
>
> ```
> losetup -D
> ```

So, you can use

```
losetup -D /dev/loop10
```

Answer (score 0):

`man umount` states

> ...  Giving the special device on which the file system lives may also work, but is obsolete, **mainly because it will fail** in case this device was mounted on more than one directory.

<sup>emphasis is mine</sup>

So the correct way is

```
umount /mnt/partition
```

From your comments I suspect there is some sort of misconception about the relation between device and mountpoint.

Whenever you unmount a device the mountpoint and the device are separated and the observed behaviour will be the same regardless if you specified the device (`/dev/loop5`) or the mountpoint (`/mnt/partition/`).

Comment: But when I'm trying to undelete files with mc it asks me for the /dev/ path, not the /mnt/ one. That's why I was trying to do it with /dev/loop all the time.

Comment: You can only undelete files as long as the directory **is** mounted. While it is mounted it doesn't really matter, how you call it.

Comment: Oh, I thought I had to unmount it first. Thanks. But still - I can't use undelete, because it asks me for the /dev/ path, while not accepting the /dev/loop5 one.